# how to stop azure vm from the file in locally

Tags: azure, shell, azure-cli

I have used the shell script to stop vm in azure portal from locally. but its not working. can anyone suggest the reason.will it require powershell script to do.Please help

```
while read rgname vmname 
do
"azure cli command to stop vm $rganme $vmname"
done < output.txt
```

i think its working only for single command through loop seems having issue.

````
rg1 vm1
rg2 vm2
rg3 vm3 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to login to azure to use AzCLI:

```
az login
```

and then you need to run the command to stop the VMs:

```
az vm deallocate -g "rgName" -n "vmName"
```

Using the output.txt file:

```
while read rgname vmname 
do
az vm deallocate -g $rgname -n $vmname
done < output.txt
```